# Set gorilla mux subrouter

Tags: go, gorilla

If I have a mux.Router, how do I set it to be a "subrouter"? All examples I can find creates a new router by calling Route.Subrouter() and then setting Handlers on it, but I already have a router!

```
// does not know about "/api/v1/"
v1_router := mux.NewRouter()
subrouter.HandleFuc("/route1/", ...)
subrouter.HandleFuc("/route2/", ...)

// does not now about route1, route2
r := mux.NewRouter()
r.PathPrefix("/api/v1/").???(v1_router)
```

I hope I'm making sense...

Comment: Can't you just call `subrouter.PathPrefix`?

Comment: And how `subrouter` is created?

Comment: @kopiczko then the subrouter has to know the pathprefix which I don't want

Comment: meanwhile, I make due with creating a router via SubRouter and passing it to a "RegisterRoutes" method

Answer (score 0):

I feel the same way, and have to live with the same "workaround". I would like to set the subrouter to an existing router. Like:

```
r.PathPrefix("/api").SetSubrouter(api.GetRouter()) //won't work
```

That would let my api feel more autonomous / loosely coupled. But *getting* a subrouter is all we have from gorilla.

```
s := r.PathPrefix("/api").Subrouter()
api.SetRoutes(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

**v1 package file:**

```
func Handlers(subrouter *mux.Router) {
    //base handler, i.e. /v1
    r.StrictSlash(true)
    subrouter.HandleFuc("/route1/", ...)
    subrouter.HandleFuc("/route2/", ...)
}
```

**main file:**

```
r := mux.NewRouter()
package.Handlers(r.PathPrefix("/api/v1").Subrouter())
```